# How to Creat MATLAB GUI for this code?

Tags: matlab

Hi everyone I wrote this code using MatLab and I need to design a GUI as the following

- Draw Button: to draw the path.
- Scan Button: If I want to take an image using "Image Acquisition"
- Static Text : to show the angels,number of objects and the centers (Individual)
- Axes : To show the image after the processing
  And is there any reference I should read to help me??

The Code:

```
im1=imread('C:\Users\Shadow Of Dark\Desktop\sample','jpeg');

im1=rgb2gray(im1);

level=graythresh(im1)

bwfram3=im2bw(im1,level);

bw2=bwareaopen(bwfram3,20);

se=strel('disk',10);

bw2=imclose(bw2,se);

bw2=imcomplement(bw2);

[labeled,numObjects] = bwlabel(bw2,4);

imshow(labeled);

numObjects

info=regionprops(labeled,'all');

centers=cat(2,info.Centroid)

hold on;

angles=zeros(1,numObjects);

j=0; 

for i=1:2:2*numObjects-2

  l = line([centers(i) centers(i+2)],[centers(i+1) centers(i+3)]);

  set(l,'linewidth',3,'color','r');

  angles(1,i-j)= atan((centers(i+1) - centers(i+3))/(centers(i) - centers(i+2)))*180/pi;
  j=j+1;
end

angles
```

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to use GUI in Matlab

Comment: It´s easy: http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/matlab-gui.html For instance, suppose you want to create a button in Matlab that runs a function when it is clicked. First of all, create a GUI layout (example.fig). An associated file is also created (example.m). If you add a button (drag and drop) in the layout, a "handler" function will also be automatically created in the example.m. If you call your function inside this one (call it just after the line of the "handler" function), you have the functionality you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, draw in a paper (or Enterprise Architect, ...) what you want and where in the layout. Afterwards, think of the sequence diagram of your process and write it in a paper. Later, divide your code into some functions, related to the steps you have described. Then, create a GUI with the GUI Editor in MATLAB and add a graphical element to your layout. Finally, link each function you have described to your graphical element (read the official help to do it).

(Alternatively, you can do it quicker mixing all these steps, but it is not an appropriate way of doing it).

Answer (score 2):

I find this list to be quite usefull for getting started:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24861-41-complete-gui-examples

You may also want to look at the examples that are already included in matlab.

Go to Start > Matlab > GUIDE

Comment: The examples which are included in the matlab didn't help me that much